# Finding Real end of document of Microsoft word

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have a word document for which i want to find the end of file.
T problem is that the document contains Images at the end currently, hence if i try finding the end , it gives me end of cursor which actually is some where above the images. I have tried

```
object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value; 
object oEoF = WdUnits.wdStory; 
wordApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.EndKey(ref oEoF, ref oMissing);
```

and finding the range of whole document to go to the end. each time i get the end of cursor (same as Ctrl+end on a normal document). I But as stated visually i have images after that.

Comment: The images are probably floating (and no inline shapes). Could you describe what you actually are trying to achieve once you got "the end" of the document?

Comment: You are right they are floating - Tight, we need the end to automate and add signatures of approving user.